# How to manage spaces in QWEB reports

Tags: javascript, css, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

My question is about customizing Qweb report in Odoo v8, if you check the image ([Report Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O29wN.jpg)) you gonna see that I have dynamic table ,so my main issue is how can I fill the free space by resizing the main coantainer? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `&#160;` to display space character in Qweb.

Answer (score 0):

**How to manage spaces in QWEB reports**

I saw your image of report. In this you have no need to fix the container height because if the record of dynamic table is large than it will automatically remove the free space.